# Accuracy issue while monitoring status of live stream with YouTube API and libcurl

Tags: c++, youtube-api, libcurl

I am using YouTube API with libcurl to check my live stream status. The code snippet is reproduced below. Most of time the response returned by the function `is_YouTubeLive` is correct. I have not checked if `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` parameter can be of some used here. How can I improve the function?

**CODE**

```
static size_t WriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
bool is_YouTubeLive()
{
    line1:
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        std::string readBuffer;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=[API KEY]");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        CURLcode response = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (response != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(response));
            return false;
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        auto quota_error = readBuffer.find("quotaExceeded");
        if (quota_error != std::string::npos) {             
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::hours(1)); // sleep for 1 hour 
            goto line1;
        }

        auto found = readBuffer.find("\"liveBroadcastContent\": \"live\"");
        if (found != std::string::npos) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what happen when it's failing, is just `is_YouTubeLive` incorrect ?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison: Reasonable question. But sadly that's the case. Sometimes but rarely, I get bad connection even when the live is healthy.

Comment: Your method of parsing JSON is very brittle; perhaps the whitespace in YouTube's response is sometimes different from what you expect?  Print the whole response to a file so you can debug it.

Comment: May you precise "I get bad connection" ? I don't see such variant for the error enumeration [as documented](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#errors).

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Agreed. I checked that if the stream health is good, the status always indicates "Live". So I summarized after debugging the JSON file.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison: Will checking the error codes fixed the issue? When YouTube is up, sometimes it reports otherwise.

Comment: I am willing to help but your question is too vague to me, it's not very clear what happen in terms of stdout/stderr, function result etc when it is working fine and when it's not.